# SVN Merge two reposiories - what about the UUIDs?

Tags: svn, repository, uuid

This is my scenario:

Originally had two seperate repositories, I need to merge these into one repository. I don't care too much about the history in these repositories. I created a new repository and can import the repositories no problem.

The issue is with users working copies, I can ask them to

> switch --relocate

them however there is the issue of the UUID which will be different for each original repository: I can only reassign the UUID in the new repository to match one of the original repositories.

So what is the best method to resolve this issue? (I suspect/hope I am going about this wrong...) Any ideas appreciated!

-Grant.

Answer (score 1):

They should only need to relocate one working copy to the new repository which (once updated) will then have all the contents of the 2 original repositories, so the second working copy can be disposed of.

You shouldn't need to worry about UUIDs at all.

Personally if this was me, and I didn't care about the history, I'd create a new blank repository, export the latest revision of both existing repositories and then import them (perhaps into parent folders in the new repository - e.g. /old-repo1/stuff, /old-repo2/stuff) then ask users to disregard both working copies and check out a new one.

Obviously make sure all users have committed all outstanding changes before you do this!